# Building an autonomic drugs widget for medical education

Tags: widget, system, medical

I've made my way over to this community because I'm planning on building a widget to help medical students with understanding the effects of various autonomic medications on cardiovascular metrics like heart rate (HR), BP (systolic, diastolic, and mean) and peripheral resistance (SVR). Some background - I'm a 3rd year med student in the US without fluency in any programming languages (which makes this particularly difficult), but am willing to spend the time to pick up what I need to know to make this happen.

Regarding the project:

The effects of autonomic medications like epinephrine, norepinephrine, beta-blockers, and alpha-blockers on the cardiovascular system is of great interest to physicians because these drugs can be used to resuscitate, to prep for surgery, to slow the progression of cardiovascular and respiratory disease, and even as antidotes for certain toxicities. There are four receptor types we are primarily concerned with - **alpha1**, **alpha2**, **beta1**, **beta2**. The receptor selectivity profile of any given drug is what governs its effects on the CV system. [The way these effects are taught and tested in med school classrooms and by the United States board exams is in the form of graphs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtjLF.jpg)

The impetus for this project is that me and many of my classmates struggled with this concept when we were initially learning it, and I believe a large part of that arises from the lack of a resource which shows the changes in the graphs from baseline, in real time.

When being taught this info, we are required to consider: a) the downstream effects when the receptor types listed above are stimulated (by an agonist drug) or inhibited (by an antagonist); b) the receptor specificities of each of the autonomic drugs of interest (there are about 8 that are *very* important); c) how to interpret the graphs shown above and [how those graphs would change if multiple autonomics were administered in succession.](https://wire.ama-assn.org/education/usmle-step-1-prep-identify-drugs-used-experiment) (Exams and the boards love to show graphs with various points marked along it, then ask which drugs are responsible for the changes seen, just like the example above.)

The current methods of learning these three points is a mess, and having gone through it, I'd like to do what I can to contribute to building a more effective resource.

My goal is to create a widget that allows a user to visualize these changes with up to 3 drugs in succession. [Here is a rough sketch of the goal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrUiH.jpg)

In this example, **norepinephrine** has strong **alpha1 agonist** effects which causes an increase in systolic (blue line), diastolic (red line), and mean BP, as well as peripheral resistance. Due to the increased BP, there is a reflexive decrease in HR.

Upon the administration of **phentolamine**, a strong **alpha1 antagonist**, the BP and SVR decline while HR increases reflexively.

Regarding the widget, I would like the user to be able to choose up to 3 drugs from a drop down menu (eg. Drug 1, Drug 2, Drug 3), and the graphs to reflect the effects of those drugs on the CV metrics while ALSO taking into account the interactions of the drugs with themselves.

This is an **IMPORTANT** point: the order in which drugs are added is important because certain receptors become blocked, preventing other drugs from having their primary effect so they revert to their secondary effect.

If you're still following me on this, what I'm looking for is some help in figuring out how best to approach all the possibilities that can happen. Should I try to understand if-then statements and write a script to produce graphs based off those? (eg. if epi, then Psys = x, Pdia = y, MAP = z). Should I create a contingency table in excel in which I list the 8 drugs I'm focusing on and make values for the metrics and then plot those, essentially taking into account all the permutations? Any thoughts and direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe you could mockup / model it in excel first or suchlike.  Work out the formulas for what needs to be drawn, and then break *that* down into pseudocode.

Comment: Well your approach will differ depending on where this widget will live? Do you want it to live on a website? Do you want a downloadable application? Do you want users to be able to change the order of the drug administration? I would come up with use cases from the users perspective which will help develop the plan of your "widget". Once you have a solid plan on how your program will operate then actually learning how to build it will be simpler. But depending on where you want your app to live will dictate the language you use to develop it so I would worry about that last.

Comment: Thank you both. The intention is for it to live on a website, and I'm guessing java/flash should be more than sufficient (?). I'm thinking I should do a mockup with 3 drugs and see how it works. It's easier for me to work out all the possibilities with 3 rather than 8. What I have in mind right now is to make an excel graph for each CV metric and drug combo. This will give me snapshots of what the graphs will look like after the drug effect(s) have taken place. From there, the challenge will be making those plots move in real time from baseline values.